# Postgres frequency count across arrays

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of text[]. How do I get a frequency count of all the objects across the column?

Example:

```
col_a   
--------
{a, b}   
{a}    
{b}    
{a}
```

Output should be:

```
col_a   | count 
----------------    
a       | 3   
b       | 2
```

My query:

```
with all_tags as (
select array_agg(c)
from (
  select unnest(tags)
  from message_tags
) as dt(c)
)

select count(*) from all_tags;
```

Comment: I think you should accept your own answer on this.

Comment: Seconded, your answer is great, wish I could give you more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

figured it out:

```
-- Collapse all tags into one array
with all_tags as (
select array_agg(c) as arr
from (
  select unnest(ner_tags)
  from message_tags
) as dt(c)
),

-- Expand single array into a row per tag
row_tags as (
select unnest(arr) as tags from all_tags
)

-- count distinct tags
select tags, count(*) from row_tags group by tags
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could just skip several steps and directly group on the unnested value:

```
select unnest(ner_tags) as tags,
       count(*) as cnt
from message_tags
group by tags
order by cnt desc
```

Since you only require a count over each of the values (no distinct or other aggregates), this is the simplest solution.