# Count freuency of array or jsonb object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In pg, there is a tags field of type `varchar`, containing tags separated by `]`, e.g `'a]b]c'`.

Need to count occurrences of these tags across multiple rows.

I know how to:

- Convert the raw string into pg array `['a', 'b', 'c']`
- and if the column is given as jsonb object  `{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}`, could count frequency via jsonb functions.

**But** I don't know how to convert pg array `['a', 'b', 'c']` into jsonb object  `{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}`, or just count frequency on array elements directly.

**The questions are:**

- A. How to convert text `'a]b]c'` into jsonb object `{'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}`, with all values as `1`.
- B. How to count frequency of array elements `['a', 'b', 'c']`, across multiple rows.

If either of the 2 questions can be solved, the original problem could be solved.
Or, there are even a better solution?

---

### @Update - To make the question more clear

If the input column is already json object, not raw string or array.

Following table show what I want to do:

```
-- create table,
create table json_aggr_learn (
    id serial8 primary key,
    uid int8,
    freq jsonb,
    created_at timestamptz default current_timestamp
);

-- init data
insert into json_aggr_learn(uid, freq) values
(1, '{"a":1, "b":2}'),
(1,'{"b":2, "c":4}'),
(2, '{"a":1, "b":2}'),
(2,'{"b":7, "c":4}'),
(2,'{"e":10, "c":4}'),
(3,'{"a":5, "c":4, "f":2}');

select * from json_aggr_learn limit 5;

-- aggr
select uid, jsonb_object_agg(key, value) as merged_freq
from
     (select id, uid, key, value
      from json_aggr_learn, jsonb_each_text(freq)
     ) as expended
group by uid
order by uid;
```

Here is the output of aggr sql:

[image: output]

Comment: Can you please give explanation to How to count frequency of array elements ['a', 'b', 'c'], across multiple rows. For Example, if 2 rows are there with row-1-col-1 = ['a','b','a'] and row-2-col1 = ['c', 'a', 'b']  what is the output you expect in terms of rows/columns?

Comment: @praxnet The expected output is `{'a':2,'b':2,'c':2}`, the order of element doesn't matter. I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486004/postgres-frequency-count-across-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [unnest()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) arrays, e.g.:

```
select id, jsonb_object_agg(tag, count) as tags
from (
    select id, unnest(string_to_array(tags, ']')) as tag, count(*)
    from my_table
    group by 1, 2
    ) s
group by 1
order by 1
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b4b8c99f93d8096af69de2c7c27f17f6)

Comment: Could you also take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787512