# Merge rows into jsonb object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

*(This is a follow up question after [Postgresql - Count freuency of array or jsonb object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65785117/))*

In `postgresql` 12+, given following input rows:

[image: rows]

The `expected` output is:

```
uid   tag_freq

1     {'a':2, 'b':1, 'c':1}
2     {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':2, 'e':1}
...
```

Output column `tag_freq` is jsonb object, and it's merged result for a user.

Is there any way to write such a query?

Comment: Sample (input) data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jsonb_object_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.12.1.2.1) for this:

```
select uid, jsonb_object_agg(tag, count) as tag_freq
from the_table
group by uid;
```